# CakePHP custom session value

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp

I build simple mobile api for android, and I generated token and add it to auth:

```
$tok = self::getToken();
$u->token = $tok;
$out = $this->Auth->setUser($u);
```

Now I add token to Auth but I don't know how I get this data. To my server I send header with this token. Maybe I do it wrong, I don't know but I can send only token to my cakephp script. Do you have any idea how I catch `$this->auth->user` via token?

Comment: Please explain it more elaborately. Are you trying to log the user in manually after assigning the token? Or are you assigning the token after it's a valid user?

Comment: At this moment I add table `token` to mysql and I catch token and user data for this table. But I think is not good idea for authorize mobile (json or angular) app ?